# How to go back to "normal" mode when using google search?

Tags: google-search

If I type something in google and click the search button; say I type "google search input field", then I will get the result. This all works fine, and I will get this:
[image]
But then if I focus on the input box of google, I will get this:
[image]
Now I realize that don't want to modify my input. The problem Is I cannot go back to the previous "status", as depicted in the first figure, unless I click the search button again(or type "Enter" key). But if I don't want to reload current page, how do I return to the previous "status"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive, through my own research, that, unless you have changed what was inside the input box, clicking enter or the search button again will not reload your current page or take you to a new one.